# Help! I've got repository access in my MVC master page! Refactor time!

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got the following code in my ***master page*** to load some customization stuff, like a css file, some address info in the footer, a header/footer logo etc. And I'm faced with load times of up to a minute! This is ***terrible*** practice, and I know - I just hacked it out to make it work. What would be the best practice of loading this type of customization information?

Currently, I try to load a cookie - check if it has the required keys, and if it doesnt - load the information from the database. I would like to have something similar to a .config file that's cached on the clients machine, if possible.

All the information is stored in a table called StoreSettings, which is linked to the Reseller table with StoreSettingsID.

```
<head id="Head1">
    <%

        HttpCookie storeSettingsCookie = Request.Cookies["StoreSettings"];
        try
        {
            if (storeSettingsCookie == null || storeSettingsCookie.HasKeys == false)
            {
                if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Context.User.IsInRole("Reseller"))
                {
                    var reseller = new Reseller();
                    var storeSettings = new StoreSettings();

                    var resellerRepository = new ResellerRepository();
                    reseller = resellerRepository.GetResellerByUsername(Context.User.Identity.Name);

                    if (reseller.StoreSettingsID != null && reseller.StoreSetting.Theme != null)
                    {
                        var storeSettingsRepository = new StoreSettingsRepository();
                        storeSettings = storeSettingsRepository.GetStoreSettings((int)reseller.StoreSettingsID);

                        storeSettingsCookie = new HttpCookie("StoreSettings");

                        storeSettingsCookie["HeaderImage"] = storeSettings.Image1.FileName;
                        storeSettingsCookie["FooterImage"] = storeSettings.Image.FileName;
                        storeSettingsCookie["ThemeLocation"] = storeSettings.Theme.StylesheetLocation;
                        storeSettingsCookie["StoreName"] = storeSettings.StoreName;
                        storeSettingsCookie["Address1"] = storeSettings.Address1;
                        storeSettingsCookie["Address2"] = storeSettings.Address2;
                        storeSettingsCookie["City"] = storeSettings.City;
                        storeSettingsCookie["PostalCode"] = storeSettings.PostalCode;
                        storeSettingsCookie["ProvinceCode"] = storeSettings.Province.Abbreviation;
                        storeSettingsCookie["Phone"] = storeSettings.Phone;

                        Response.Cookies.Add(storeSettingsCookie);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        storeSettingsCookie = new HttpCookie("StoreSettings");

                        storeSettingsCookie["ThemeLocation"] = "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css";
                        storeSettingsCookie["StoreName"] = "";
                        storeSettingsCookie["Address1"] = "";
                        Response.Cookies.Add(storeSettingsCookie);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }


    %>
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
        |
        <%: string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeSettingsCookie["StoreName"]) ? "My Store Name" : storeSettingsCookie["StoreName"] %>
    </title>

... <%-- Css/JS --%>

</head>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. I expect a lot of sighs from the MVC guys. I know this isn't how MVC is supposed to work, so please refrain from reminding me of that, haha. :)

*edit*

Okay, so following LukLed's advice, I've created a base controller class, stuck the code above in its constructor and had my controllers inherit it. This appears like it is going to work, however the User object is null. How should I work around this? Here's what I've got:

```
  public BaseController()
        {
            var resellerRepository = new ResellerRepository();
            var reseller = resellerRepository.GetResellerByUsername(User.Identity.Name);

            if (reseller.StoreSettingsID != null && reseller.StoreSetting.Theme != null)
            {
                var storeSettingsRepository = new StoreSettingsRepository();
                var storeSettings = storeSettingsRepository.GetStoreSettings((int)reseller.StoreSettingsID);

                ViewData["HeaderImage"] = storeSettings.Image1.FileName;
                ViewData["FooterImage"] = storeSettings.Image.FileName;
                ViewData["ThemeLocation"] = storeSettings.Theme.StylesheetLocation;
                ViewData["StoreName"] = storeSettings.StoreName;
                ViewData["Address1"] = storeSettings.Address1;
                ViewData["Address2"] = storeSettings.Address2;
                ViewData["City"] = storeSettings.City;
                ViewData["PostalCode"] = storeSettings.PostalCode;
                ViewData["ProvinceCode"] = storeSettings.Province.Abbreviation;
                ViewData["Phone"] = storeSettings.Phone;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["ThemeLocation"] = "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css";
                ViewData["StoreName"] = "";
                ViewData["Address1"] = "";
            }
        }
```

The reseller must be logged on in order to view the store.

*edit*

So here is where I am at after following Darins advice - I upgraded to MVC3 and used a GlobalActionFilter, which is executing after EVERY action called. How do I prevent this - because it executes 4-5 times. Also - the viewdata is null every time. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my action filter (I didn't use Automapper from Darin's example because StoreSettings doesn't translate directly to StoreSettingsViewModel, and I wanted to see this working, first)

```
 public class StoreSettingsActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IResellerRepository _resellerRepository;
        private readonly IStoreSettingsRepository _storeSettingsRepository;

        public StoreSettingsActionFilter(
            IResellerRepository resellerRepository,
            IStoreSettingsRepository storeSettingsRepository
        )
        {
            _resellerRepository = resellerRepository;
            _storeSettingsRepository = storeSettingsRepository;
        }

        public StoreSettingsActionFilter()
            : this(new ResellerRepository(), new StoreSettingsRepository())
        {

        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

            var settingsViewModel = new StoreSettingsViewModel();
            settingsViewModel.ThemeLocation = "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css";
            var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !user.IsInRole("Reseller"))
            {
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData["storeSettings"] = settingsViewModel;
                return;
            }

            var session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            var reseller = session["reseller"] as Reseller;
            if (reseller == null)
            {
                reseller = _resellerRepository.GetResellerByUsername(user.Identity.Name);
                session["reseller"] = reseller;
            }

            if (reseller.StoreSettingsID != null && reseller.StoreSetting.Theme != null)
            {
                var storeSettings = session["storeSettings"] as StoreSettings;
                if (storeSettings == null)
                {
                    storeSettings = _storeSettingsRepository.GetStoreSettings((int)reseller.StoreSettingsID);
                    session["storeSettings"] = storeSettings;
                }
                // Using AutoMapper to convert between the model and the view model
                //settingsViewModel = Mapper.Map<StoreSettings, StoreSettingsViewModel>(storeSettings);

                settingsViewModel.ThemeLocation = storeSettings.Theme.StylesheetLocation;
                settingsViewModel.Address1 = storeSettings.Address1;
                settingsViewModel.Address2 = storeSettings.Address2;
                settingsViewModel.City = storeSettings.City;
                settingsViewModel.FooterImage = storeSettings.Image.FileName;
                settingsViewModel.HeaderImage = storeSettings.Image1.FileName;
                settingsViewModel.Phone = storeSettings.Phone;
                settingsViewModel.PostalCode = storeSettings.PostalCode;
                settingsViewModel.ProvinceCode = storeSettings.Province.Abbreviation;
                settingsViewModel.StoreName = storeSettings.StoreName;
            }
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["storeSettings"] = settingsViewModel;
        }
    }
```

Here is where i register the global action filter

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    //Register the global action filter
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new StoreSettingsActionFilter());

    //RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that would take up to a minute

Comment: This is not how MVC is supposed to work. If it takes up to a minute, probably this view is not the worst part of your project. Repositories are. How do `Repository.Get(...)` methods look like?  Maybe you are performing search after getting all rows from database. Something like `context.Clients.ToList().Where(...)`.

Comment: Empty catch block, nice.

Comment: You seem to be using web forms and not MVC => <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />

Comment: @LukLed i am doing that in a few places. But regardless - this shouldn't be on the master page. period. Where would it go? I can address the query stuff later. @Ian Nelson I know, it's pro, right? haha. @santiagoIT I'm not using webforms, MVC fo sho! When I saw that at first I was confused as well - because that was automatically generated for me.

Comment: @Gallen: First of all, you should have base controller, which could place required data in `ViewData` or `ViewBag`. you could overwrite `OnActionExecuting` method or place this data in action filter. If it takes a minute, it should be very slow SQL.

Comment: @LukLed I think you hit the nail on the head with the slow queries - because I'm definitely doing that for loading my menus. How would the base controller work, would I make a constructor method load the information, stick it in `ViewBag` inside the base controller and have all of my controllers inherit this class?

Comment: @Gallen: That is general idea. Start by doing it (place code in constructor). Then, when it works, move it to better place (like action filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an action filter that will inject the store settings on each request. The view model could look like this:

```
public class StoreSettingsViewModel
{
    public string HeaderImage { get; set; }
    public string FooterImage { get; set; }
    public string ThemeLocation { get; set; }
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string ProvinceCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

And the action filter:

```
public class StoreSettingsActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IResellerRepository _resellerRepository;
    private readonly IStoreSettingsRepository _storeSettingsRepository;

    public StoreSettingsActionFilter(
        IResellerRepository resellerRepository,
        IStoreSettingsRepository storeSettingsRepository
    )
    {
        _resellerRepository = resellerRepository;
        _storeSettingsRepository = storeSettingsRepository;
    }

    public StoreSettingsActionFilter() 
        : this(new ResellerRepository(), new StoreSettingsRepository())
    { }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        var settingsViewModel = new StoreSettingsViewModel();
        settingsViewModel.ThemeLocation = "~/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css";
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !user.IsInRole("Reseller"))
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["storeSettings"] = settingsViewModel;
            return;
        }

        var session = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var reseller = session["reseller"] as Reseller;
        if (reseller == null)
        {
            reseller = _resellerRepository.GetResellerByUsername(user.Identity.Name);
            session["reseller"] = reseller;
        }

        if (reseller.StoreSettingsID != null && reseller.StoreSetting.Theme != null)
        {
            var storeSettings = session["storeSettings"] as StoreSettings;
            if (storeSettings == null)
            {
                storeSettings = _storeSettingsRepository.GetStoreSettings((int)reseller.StoreSettingsID);
                session["storeSettings"] = storeSettings;
            }
            // Using AutoMapper to convert between the model and the view model
            settingsViewModel = Mapper.Map<StoreSettings, StoreSettingsViewModel>(storeSettings);
        }
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["storeSettings"] = settingsViewModel;
    }
}
```

Now we need to apply this attribute on the base controller so that it is executed for each action:

```
[StoreSettings]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you could have a [global action filter](http://blog.tallan.com/2011/02/04/global-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3/).

And finally inside the master page you would have access to the store settings:

```
<% 
    var storeSettings = (StoreSettingsViewModel)ViewData["storeSettings"];
%>

<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    <%: storeSettings.StoreName ?? "My Store Name" %>
</title>
<%-- Css/JS --%>
...
```

Comment: I would add additional `boolean` parameter to attribute, so you can decorate action with `StoreSettingsActionFilter(false)` and resign from setting these data in some actions (ajax, partial...).

Comment: Thanks Darin - pro advice as always!

Comment: I spoke too soon - the global action filter runs several times, and then the ViewData is coming out null when I get to the master page. How would I prevent this from running multiple times (is that what you were talking about @LukLed?) And what should I look for when debugging the null viewdata?

Comment: @Gallen: I wouldn't use global action filter, but the way Darin described.

Comment: I can apply the filter to controller actions themselves, right?

Comment: If you put this on BaseController that implys that all of your views are going to be using this master page for that view. How would you go about doing this for ONLY that master page? I think you can just include that filter on the actions that just apply that master page but this seems ugly.. Is there a way to detect in the action filter if the current action is using that master page layout?